# Code Movie Wall

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle, movies, connect-wall

<sub>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36: Twisted Classics 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372)</sub>

---

I'm thinking of a movie. The [Connecting Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Connect#Round_3:_Connecting_Wall) below (click it for a bigger version) should have made guessing the movie really simple, but apparently some cruel hackers used a [0day](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/187929/81279) vulnerability in Puzzling.SE and replaced all movie titles with Java code.

Nevertheless, your task remains the same. Group the items into 4 groups of 4 items which share a common property. Then tell me the title of the movie I'm thinking of.

[image: wall]

**Transcript**

```
/* A */
void refuse(String offer) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

/* B */
Object getSpoon() {
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}

/* C */
void operator() {
    waitUntil(LocalTime.of(13, 13));
    launch();
}

/* D */
void fill(Plot p) {
    while (!fedEx.isEmpty()) {
        p.addScene(fedEx.remove());
    }
}

/* E */
void process(BitSet guilty) {
    while (!guilty.isEmpty()) {
        guilty.set(random.nextInt(12), false);
    }
}

/* F */
void init(Map<Object, Integer> priceList) {
    priceList.put(woodenSword, 20000);
    priceList.put(aluminiumSword, 70000);
    priceList.put(cuirass, 125000);
}

/* G */
void printName() {
    for (char c : "IBM".toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print((char) (c - 1));
    }
}

/* H */
Object answer(String question) {
    return Duration.of(2, WEEK);
}

/* I */
void show(Plot p) {
    for (Scene s : p.getScenes().reverse()) {
        show(s);
    }
}

/* J */
void check(long epochMilli) {
    assert epochMilli >= 329702400000L &&
            epochMilli < 329788800000L;
}

/* K */
Object getBathroom() {
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}

/* L */
void play() {
    throw new Baseball("#000000");
}

/* M */
void process(Object o) {
    try {
        o.getClass().getMethod("erase").invoke(o);
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}

/* N */
@Override
boolean isVisible() {
    return super.isVisible() || isDead();
}

/* O */
void check(double lat, double lon) {
    assert lat < 37 || lat > 40 ||
            lon > -94.6 || lon < -102;
}

/* P */
Object getTerminator() {
    return sylvesterStallone;
}
```

Comment: "get spoon" lol

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Community Wiki (since I'm unlikely to be familiar with all the movies)

> A [The Godfather](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/) (an offer you can't refuse)
>  B [The Matrix](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133093/) (there is no spoon)
>  C [Apollo 13](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112384/) (launch at 1:13pm)
>  D [Cast Away](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0162222/)  (Chuck Noland is a FedEx exec)
>  E [12 Angry Men](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050083/) (voting not guilty)
>  F [Gladiator](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172495/) (Price props were bought for)
>  G [2001: A Space Odyssey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/?ref_=nv_sr_3) (The computer HAL is from IBM letters shifted one back)
>  H [Total Recall](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/)
>  I [Memento](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/) (plot told out of order)
>  J [Friday the 13th](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080761/) (Epoch time lies between June 12 and 13th, the dates of Friday the 13th)
>  K [Kindergarten Cop](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099938/) (THERE IS NO BATHROOM!)
>  L [Pitch Black](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134847/) (Throw = pitch, #000000 = black)
>  M [Eraser](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116213/)
>  N [The Sixth Sense](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167404/) thanks to Nicolas Budig. (I see dead people)
>  O [The Wizard of Oz](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032138/) (Not in Kansas)
>  P [Last Action Hero](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107362/) (Sylvester Stallone is featured as the Terminator on a Terminator 2 poster)

Which means the [connect-wall](/questions/tagged/connect-wall) would be

> [image: Connect Wall]

Which can be solved like so:

> Eraser, Last Action Hero, Kindergarten Cop, Total Recall ([Arnold Schwarzenegger](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000216/))
>  Cast Away, Gladiator, Memento, Pitch Black (made in 2000)
>  The Godfather, The Matrix, The Sixth Sense, The Wizard of Oz (prefix "The")
>  12 Angry Men, Apollo 13, 2001: A Space Odyssey, Friday the 13th (contain numbers that are not spelled out)

The movie you are thinking about then must be

> [The 6th Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_6th_Day), which came out in 2000, stars Arnold Schwarzenegger, starts with "The" and has a number in its title.

Comment: The lively community effort to find all the answers here has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82350/discussion-on-answer-by-david-starkey-code-movie-wall). Most of these comments were [ROT-13 encoded](http://www.rot13.com/) to preserve the mystery for other solvers, so keep that in mind as you revisit the comments now preserved in chat.